# Convert all links to images in a Google Document with actual images

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I've got a few Google Docs that contain some paragraphs of text and multiple Drive links in the following format:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=XXXX
```

How can I use a script to replace all the links in the Google Doc with the images that the links direct to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a script for this purpose.  It uses `findText` method to locate the links. Once a link is found, the element containing it is inspected: its text content is matched again against the link format, this time using string `match` method of plain JavaScript. The reason is that findText does not offer an easy way to retrieve the content that was actually matched...

Anyway, once the id is obtained from `text.match`, the image is acquired and appended to the element's parent. The logic is that the element we are looking at is probably Text, and Text cannot contain other elements. So the parent (probably Paragraph) is used instead.

The `appendInlineImage` method appends it at the end of paragraph. There is also [`insertInlineImage`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#insertinlineimagechildindex-image) which allows for finer positioning, but it operates in terms of element index, not text offset. To my inderstanding, to insert an image directly where its URL is found, one would have to replace the original Text element by two, putting an image in between two pieces. This seemed too complicated to me, so I left it at `appendInlineImage`.

At the very end, all matching URLs are removed with `replaceText` method.

```
function replaceLinksByImages() {
  var searchPattern = "https://drive.google.com/open\\?id=\\w+";
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var found = body.findText(searchPattern); 
  while (found) {
    var elem = found.getElement();
    var text = elem.getText();
    var match = text.match(/https:\/\/drive.google.com\/open\?id=(\w+)/);
    if (match) {
      var id = match[1];
      var image = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob();
      elem.getParent().appendInlineImage(image);
    }
    found = body.findText(searchPattern, found);
  }
  body.replaceText(searchPattern, "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, \w+ only searches for word characters, and "-" is not included. Your code, @Curious, didn't work for me, but I really liked the new width thing. I've changed \w+ for \S+, which searchs for non-whitespace characters, and mantained the NewWidth functionality. It is working fine for me.

```
function replaceLinksByImages() {
  var searchPattern = "https://drive.google.com/open\\?id=\\S+";
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var found = body.findText(searchPattern); 
  while (found) {
    var elem = found.getElement();
    var text = elem.getText();
    var match = text.match(/https:\/\/drive.google.com\/open\?id=(\S+)/);
    if (match) {
      var id = match[1];
      var image = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob();
      var appendImage = elem.getParent().appendInlineImage(image);
      var width = appendImage.getWidth()
      var height = appendImage.getHeight()
      var ratio = height/width

      var NewWidth = 320

      appendImage.setWidth(NewWidth).setHeight(NewWidth*ratio)
    }
    found = body.findText(searchPattern, found);
  }
  body.replaceText(searchPattern, "");
}
```

Change the NewWidth to your preferred width. I use docs with two columns, so 320 is fine.

A huge thanks to both of you!

**edit**: at least for me, Google now creates its links of the form "/file/d/IDHERE/view?usp=sharing" instead of "/open?id=". I've changed the regex so it works. So, change the first regex to

```
var searchPattern = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/\\S+";
```

and the second to

```
var match = text.match(/https:\/\/drive.google.com\/file\/d\/(\S+)\/view/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @FTP, that did the trick! I was having some issues with an address containing a "-" character as well as resizing the images, so I ended up adding the following to your code:

```
function replaceLinksByImages(){
  var searchPattern = "https://drive.google.com/open\?id=\S+";
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var found = body.findText(searchPattern); 
  while (found) {
    var elem = found.getElement();
    var text = elem.getText();
    var match = text.match(/https://drive.google.com/open\?id=([\w-]+)/);
    if (match) {
      var id = match[1];
      var image = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob();
      var appendImage = elem.getParent().appendInlineImage(image);
      var width = appendImage.getWidth()
      var height = appendImage.getHeight()
      var ratio = width/height
      var NewH = 640/ratio
```

appendImage.setWidth(640).setHeight(NewH)
    }
    found = body.findText(searchPattern, found);
  }
  body.replaceText(searchPattern, "");
}

Thanks again.